# MYSQL CONV from Hexadecimal to Decimal issue

Tags: mysql

I have some code that converts numbers from Hexadecimal to Decimal, and checks to see if greater than or equal to. Today, I discovered this doesn't always work, and I have no idea why.

I have tried using the raw values, and that works. Conversions outside of the compare work.

```
select case when 5 >= 40 then 'Fail' else 'Pass' end as 'Check';

select case  WHEN CONV('0005',16,10) >= CONV('28',16,10) THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' end as 'Check';

select CONV('0005',16,10) as '1', CONV('28',16,10) as '2';
```

The first select works as intended (Pass). The second select does not. The third select just shows that the conversion is working properly (i.e. 0005 HEX = 5 Decimal, and 28 Hex = 40 Decimal).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv):

> `CONV(N,from_base,to_base)`
>
> ... Returns a string representation of the
>   number N ...

The results are strings and compared as such. For strings `'5' > '40'`. So you need to cast the ressults either explicitly with `CAST`

```
select case
    WHEN CAST(CONV('0005',16,10) as SIGNED) >= CAST(CONV('28',16,10) as SIGNED )
        THEN 'Fail'
    else 'Pass' end
as 'Check';
```

or implicitly with a numeric operation like `+0`

```
select case  WHEN CONV('0005',16,10)+0 >= CONV('28',16,10)+0 THEN 'Fail' else 'Pass' end as 'Check';
```

If you know the max length of the HEX strings, you could also fill them with zeros using `LPAD()`

```
select case
    WHEN lpad('0005', 20, 0) >= lpad('28', 20, 0)
        THEN 'Fail'
    else 'Pass'
end as 'Check';
```